# Is scalpel-free vasectomy safe and effective?

Tags: sex

While researching online, I [read about scalpel free vasectomy](http://www.mensclinic.com/no-scalpel-vasectomy/). With any procedure, there are risks and benefits.  How safe and effective is this procedure?  How does that compare with a traditional vasectomy procedure?

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here, so I edited your question to eliminate the personal details. You can revert my edits if you disagree, but that will likely result in your question being closed as off topic.

Comment: Also, as a courtesy to other members, please research your question on your own and share what you find. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center > Asking](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Thanks!

Comment: If you are not sure where to search for reliable information, see the discussion on Health Meta, titled [What are reliable sources?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources), which contains links to many journals, databases, and search engines.

Comment: As @CareyGregory said: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here. By reverting his edit, your question becomes off-topic and I therefore vote to close it.

Comment: I understand that you didn't revert the whole edit, and you left out the most problematic parts, but still there is too much personal detail and the question gets close to personal medical advice question. Perhaps the middle ground could be saying that you have 3 children already and that after exploring other birth control options you are thinking of this one? Something along those lines, leaving out the age and the specifics. Although the best way to salvage your question/leave it open would be to follow Carey's edit.

Comment: I agree with the above.  I understand what you're asking, ChristinaH, but you need to do it differently on Stack Exchange. I'm giving it one more go with editing to see if you'll accept it, @ChristinaH, otherwise I vote close.